# Company mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I'm new to Emacs (1 week or so) and I'm struggling with some config. Sorry if I sound newbie. I've tried many differents things for the two last days. Here what I want to setup:

- Emacs with Melpa to install packages
- company-mode to auto complete
- company-irony to auto complete c/c++
- company-c-headers to auto complete c headers

So, I installed these 3 packages with Melpa.

I then edited my `~/.emacs` to:

```
 ; MELPA
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

; COMPANY
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

; COMPANY HEADERS C
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)

; COMPANY IRONY
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-irony))
```

But no matter what I try, I have no auto completion whatsoever!  What's wrong?

Comment: Too broad and unclear. Specify a specific problem or question. Provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically, I added the MELPA section in my emacs init file. I then installed the 3 packages mentionned. And finally I added the COMPANY section in my init file.
When I edit a .cpp file, I have no completion.
I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: http://github.com/iced/.emacs.d - take a look at my config. no c/c++ support there, but quite some languages with company completion to get you started.

Comment: Wow thanks ! You're  ue-ensure-installed function will be usefull ! But I still don't understand what's wrong in my config. Shouldn't It be sufficient ? Thanks again

Comment: Problem solved thanks to your emacs file ! I had my require 'company after the use of the company mode (stupid me !).
I also had to install irony to use company-irony since company-irony is just a backend for irony ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Nice! As you are starting w/ emacs, I strongly suggest to start with one of the prebuilt .emacs.d - not sure if my will go (it was not intended for mass or neophyte usage) but something like https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude will get you nice overview what you'll be able to do with your emacs.